# How to generate a random string RANDBETWEEN?

Tags: excel, random

I'm using this formula to generate a random code:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,9))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(33,47))&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,9))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(33,47))
```

Instead of something that looks like this:`6Ib&4Rj/`, I get

> NAME? error

Anybody can see where I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`RANDBETWEEN` requires the first argument to be less than the second argument.

Replace all instances of `RANDBETWEEN(65,9)` with `RANDBETWEEN(9,65)` and that should fix your problem.